# Loading several BLOB from sql database into ListView in C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, listview, blob

I am trying to load some BLOB-files (some random pictures) into a ListView in C#. I can read one picture out of the database if I use a select statement like this:

"Select picture from Picture where id = 1" for example.

But how can I read all pictures from the database? I've tried this code:

```
public List<Bitmap> fetchPictures()
        {
            List<Bitmap> mPictures = new List<Bitmap>();
            DataTable dt;
            sql = "SELECT picture FROM Picture";

                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 6);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    byte[] MyData = new byte[0];
                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    da.Fill(ds, "Picture");
                    dt = ds.Tables["Picture"];
                    DataRow myRow;

                    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        myRow = dt.Rows[i];
                        MyData = (byte[])myRow["Picture"];
                        mStream.Write(MyData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(MyData.Length));
                        mPictures.Add(new Bitmap(mStream, false));
                    }

                    mStream.Dispose();
                    return mPictures;
                }

        }
```

As you can see I try to read all the Pictures and add them then to a List of Bitmaps. The database is currently filled with two different pictures. If I run the program the ListView has two pictures, but they are both the first picture of the database. So I guess the problem must be in this method.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code to have this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        myRow = dt.Rows[i];
        MyData = (byte[])myRow["Picture"];
        mStream.Write(MyData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(MyData.Length));
        mPictures.Add(new Bitmap(mStream, false));
    }
}
```

I think, your stream may just still starts with first picture

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! But I don't really get what the problem was. Could you maybe explain it to me?

Comment: You declared your stream outside of for-loop. And it kept on adding more data. So, when you did `new Bitmap(mStream, false)`, it loaded both bitmaps actually, on the second row, but you only saw 1. Now, you creating one stream for each bitmap.

Comment: No problem - enjoy coding